# Choosing the right tools/program to develop a web application

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to develop a web application,I work alone (not with a team),so I should choose my tools alone, I want to have a advice about what should I use.
I am thinking about using Java EE:
JSF and primefaces for the presentation layer
tomcat as the server
eclipse as the IDE
JPA/Hibernate for the mapping
Oracle as the database
and I wonder should I use spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different tools for developing web applications. All have their strengths and their weaknesses.

It really boils down to which you are most comfortable with.

If you're a programmer then pick a tool which uses a language that is closest to what you are most proficient in.

If you're not a programmer then choose an all in one tool that will generate the code for you, leaving you to design the look and feel of it.

Then there is cost. Some of the tools are open source and free, many are not, but if your pockets aren't deep then you may have to pick a language that you're not comfortable with.

You don't say whether you're developing this as a private individual or as an employee.

I would guess if you're looking at Oracle as a database rather than MySQL or an SQL Server derivative then you're working as an employee. Some companies will restrict what tools you can use so that they can ensure support after you've left.

Bear in mind that the user doesn't care what has been used to implement the application, but the host may - espcially if it requires specific libraries/tools installed to run.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a Java EE application that among others uses JSF and JPA, a MUCH easier choice than Tomcat is to download a server that already includes all of this.

Examples of those are GlassFish, JBoss AS, TomEE and Resin.

With Java EE 6, there is no need for Spring anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle JDeveloper 11g. It is all in one IDE which will help you from Design to development and till debugging. You can also design and model databases required etc.

Visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html